# On Maschke type theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Maschke theorem can be formulated in number of ways.

One way is: Let $G$ be a finite group and let $K$ be a field with charectersic not divied the order of $G$ then any irreducible rep. of $G$ admits a complament.
In other words the group algebra $KG$ is semi-simple.

There are some areas with "Maschke type theorems". For examples it can easily generalized for projective rep., that is under our non-modularity conditions any irreducible $f$-projective rep. adimt a complament, in other words, the twisted group algebra $K^fG$ is also semi-simple.

Another example is in graded theory: Let $V$ be a $G$-graded module. If $W$ is a graded submoudule which admits a complament as submodule then it admits a complament as a graded sub-module.

On the other hand we know some examples in which we do not have "Maschke theorem".

A subgroup (even normal) $N$ of $G$ not always have a "complament".

In linear algebra when given $T:V\rightarrow V$ an invariant subspace of $T$ not always have an invariant complament.

I hope someone can give more examples and also to try to explain in which "cases" we should expect "Maschke type theorems" and in which cases we should not. I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: The standard Maschke Theorem works in situations when $|G|$ is invertible in the field, and not otherwise. So, for example, it does not work for representations over ${\mathbb Z}$. Note also that the cohomology groups $H^n(G,M)$ for an $RG$-module $M$ are zero when $|G|$ is invertible over $R$, which result in splitting theorems like the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem in group theory.

Comment: Is it known for the case of differential graded modules? i.e., if M is a DG-module and N is a DG-submodule of M which admits a complement as a submodule, then does it admit a complement as a DG-submodule too?